# C# - make a string print to console differently but be used elsewhere in its original form

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, string-formatting, tostring

I have a weird question. Here it goes -

Let's consider the below code snippet:

```
string test ="this is a test string";
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

I want it to print a different thing - like `yup, this is a test string`. Actually, I want to see if the string is matching some pattern, and if so I want it printed differently. I want that to be the case only when I am printing it to console, but whenever I am using it elsewhere, it should be the original one.

I was hoping I could write an extension method on String class ( or Object class? ) and make ToString() return as per my needs, but the docs say:

> An extension method will never be
>   called if it has the same signature as
>   a method defined in the type.

Is there any possibility of doing such a thing? I cannot use a new type. Or maybe trying to make ToString() behave differently is not the way to go. But is there a way to make a particular string print to the console differently but be used in its original form elsewhere?

Comment: You can't do this unless you make an entirely new type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static void WriteToConsole(this string text)
    {
        string result;
        if (<matches1>)
            result = "111";
        else if (<matches1>)
            result = "222";
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
string test = "this is a test string";
test.WriteToConsole();
```

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking this is the way I have to go. But I was hoping for `Console.WriteLine(result)` to do that. There is no point in having an "extension" method if I have to do this right? I can just have a method / function.

Comment: Extension method is just a static method that provides you with more intuitive way to call it. You can do either `StringExtension.WriteToConsole(text)` or `test.WriteToConsole()`. Both of those will result with the same IL compiled. Yes, you might want to create private static method and call it rather than having public extension method. Which way to go is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can implement [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) and pass it to `Console.WriteLine`.

To make it use by default you can try to make custom [CultureInfo] ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) and set it to be used by your app.

Never tried this, so caveat emptor.